# How do I insert into a range but keep relative references the same?

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I have a named range that I need to be able to insert rows into. Some of the cells contain formulas that reference the cell above. For example, if the range was A2:A4, A2 is =B2-B1, A3 is =B3-B2, and A4 is = B4-B3 and so on (i.e. a running total).

When I insert a new row at A3 (making my range A2:A5), the formula in A4 now reads B4-B2 and A5 reads B5 - B3. I need the formula in A4 to remain as B4-B3 and A5 to remain B5-B4 even though I inserted. Basically I need the relative references to 'bump' down a row with the row that gets bumped down at the insert.

I cannot make this a table--it is formatted 'for printing'. I've tried various forms of indirect and they don't work. I cannot simply select A2 and fill-handle down to fix things (the insert is done through VBA across dozens of named ranges).

The main use of this is to add a blank row at the bottom of a named range that is included in the range. I select the bottom row of the range(lastrow), insert at it (creating a blank row above and keeping lastrow within the named range), copy the values/formulas in lastrow ad paste them into the blank row above, clear lastrow(now a new blank row at the bottom of the range but still within it), and paste formulas and formatting back into the new blank bottom row. This lets me add a new row at the bottom of the range with formulas/formatting copied (similar to a fill handle) but blanks where values need to be entered. All of that is working, its only when some of the formulas reference cells above them that this breaks.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the insert code (part of it):

```
Sub expand_range( _
                    target_range As Range, _
                    Optional num_rows As Integer = 1, _
                    Optional insert_entire_sheet_row As Boolean = False, _
                    Optional keep_formulas As Boolean = False _
                    )

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo Cleanup

Dim original_cell As Range: Set original_cell = ActiveCell
Dim last_row As Range: Set last_row = target_range.Rows(target_range.Rows.Count)
Dim last As Integer

last = target_range.Rows.Count

' Insert new row(s) above the last row and copy contents from last row to the new one(s)
IIf(insert_entire_sheet_row, last_row.Cells(1).EntireRow, last_row) _
    .Resize(num_rows).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
last_row.Copy
last_row.Offset(-num_rows).PasteSpecial
last_row.ClearContents

On Error Resume Next ' This will fail if there are no formulas and keep_formulas = True
    If keep_formulas Then
        With last_row.Offset(-num_rows)
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Select
            .Copy
            .Offset(1).Resize(num_rows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            .Offset(1).Resize(num_rows).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: Why don't you share the code which you use at the moment, the one that does what you described in the last part of your post? A list of the named ranges' names and their addresses may come in handy, too.

Comment: Use [absolute references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) maybe?

Comment: I added the insert code; theres a lot of ranges that all get inserted into at once so that's too much to list.

Comment: I would try to create a dynamic named range that can adjust automatically to what you need, including an extra empty row at the bottom of a given range. Then use those named ranges in your VBA if necessary.

Comment: That was essentially Greek to me, sorry! Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out at least one solution, which is to use OFFSET. It appears that when you insert a row, Excel treats references to cells in the same row as your formula as relative and updates them, but treats references to cells in different rows in your formula as absolute (regardless of if they are) and does not. Thus, if your formula in A5 says = B5-B4, an you insert at A5, your A6 now says = B6-B4 (and not B6-B5, hence my original problem).

So I changed this to A5 is =B5 - (OFFSET(B5, -1, 0)), and when inserting, A6 is now =B6 - (OFFSET(B6,-1,0). (The actual formulas are much more complicated but that's the gist of it.) Obviously this will be much more difficult to implement in more complicated formulas with different types of references, but at least it works for this!